# JQuery Youtube Embed On Click CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change css of an element when onclick iframe so when play to video css will change and when pause video css will return. I know JQuery and i tried to do that but its not worked.

Following Code:

```
$(".video-post").on("click", function() {
    $(".video-post ELEMENT").css("display", "none");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="post-media video-post embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A5mM6VOVMk4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <time datetime="2017">July 21, 2017</time>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried $this.css("display", "none"); or $(this).hide();

Comment: Not working and i want to set transition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".video-post").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Its samething like i did.

Comment: post the html so we can assist.   If the iframe has the class "video-post" than what I wrote will work.

Comment: posted check please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new class to represent the playing state.

In CSS, you may add:

```
.video-playing{
  display:none;
}
.video-paused{
  display:inline;
}
```

You can use jquery method .hasClass() to see if the class exist in the element.
You may try this code:

```
$(".video-post").click(function(){
  if($(".video-post ELEMENT").hasClass()){
    $(".video-post ELEMENT").removeClass("video-playing").addClass(".video-paused");
  }else{
    $(".video-post ELEMENT").removeClass(".video-paused").addClass("video-playing");
  }
});
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Its not working its about youtube api i am searched little bit its abot youtube api but still i couldnt.